# SonataAdminBundle sonata_type_collection not showing field

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-admin

I am using SonataAdminBundle. I want to add in my creation form ability to add one to many ralation objects. So I am trying to use sonata_type_collection like this:

```
$formMapper->add('attachments', 'sonata_type_collection', array(
                    'label' => 'Attachments',
                    // Prevents the "Delete" option from being displayed
                    'type_options' => array('delete' => false)
                ), array(
                    'edit' => 'inline',
                    'inline' => 'table',
                    'sortable' => 'position',
                ))
```

But my creation form renders only a label of the field, nothing more.

Thanks for all suggestions in advance :)

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this:

```
        ->add('attachments', 'sonata_type_collection', array(
            'label' => 'Attachments',
        ), array(
            'class' => 'Model:Name',
            'target_entity' => '\\Namespace\\To\\Entity',
            'allow_delete' => false,
            'multiple' => true,
            'expanded' => false,
            'admin_code' => 'sonata.admin.setting',
            'edit' => 'inline',
            'inline' => 'table',
        ))
```

Comment: Thx for your reply. Can you explain what is Model:Name and admin_code ?

Comment: `Model:Name` would be the entity shortcut name you can use with doctrine instead of the full class name. See http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html#fetching-objects-from-the-database so your model would be something like `Acme\DemoBundle\Entity\EntityName` or you could use `AcmeDemoBundle:EntityName`

Comment: The `admin_code` would be explained here. http://sonata-project.org/bundles/admin/2-0/doc/reference/form_types.html#field-configuration hopefully this helps.

Comment: OK so I am clearly missing something. When I do what you suggest attamchemts shows on editing an object but not on creating page.

Comment: It works, thanks you so much, i was looking for such an answer for weeks now